# ISR not working in django server but in next dev server

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, next.js

hello i recently ran into an error, when i try to do ISR in django python server it fails but when i do in next dev server it works.. on dev server when i update content in django admin panel it changes in dev server , but when in production mode we use django server and it would not work there , whats the solution..

index.js

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Posts from '../comps/Posts'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'



export default function Home({data}) {
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div>
     {data.map(e=>{
               return(
               <div>
                   <h1 id='data_h1'>{e.username}</h1>
               </div>
               )
            })}
   </div>

 )
}


export async function getStaticProps() {

  const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/userprofile_data/');
  const data = await res.json();

  return {props: {data}, revalidate: 1 };
```

}

Comment: Are you hardcoding the server base URL as `http://127.0.0.1:8000`? That's probably not the right URL when deployed to production.

Comment: In development yes , but in production will change it

Answer (score 0):

In `const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/userprofile_data/');` you are fetching from localhost (127.0.0.1), it means your dev computer. In production, it runs on a different computer, so without access to.
In order to fix it, you need (from what I know) to deploy your Django server and pass the URL. Following this path, I suggest you use environment variables to keep different base URLs for development and production.